# access controller from object

Tags: jquery, ember.js

I have a `currentUser` controller that works for me most of the time.

I'm adding a `findAll()` to an `Ember.Object` in order to get all the projects from the server. I only want to get the projects for the `currentUser`, and I'm somehow trying to incorporate the `currentUserController` to get to the `id` of the user that is logged in.

1. Is accessing a controller from a model incorrect usage?
2. If not, how should I get to the controller?

```
App.Project = Ember.Object.reopenClass({
    findAll: function() {
    allPosts = [];
    $.ajax({
      url: '/projects.json',
      type: 'GET',
      data: {'user_id': App.currentUserController.id},
      success: function(data, textStatus, xhr){

      },
      error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {

      }
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the conventional wisdom is that a model should never access a controller.

Does your `currentUserController` have an accompanying route and template? What I mean to ask is, if not, does `currentUserController` simply serve as a global variable? If so, you might just want to store `currentUserController.id` at `App.currentUserId` and refer to it as needed. Not everybody likes global variables, but this would be a reasonable place to use one.

Answer (score 0):

Note that this is not really secure because the variable can be changed by a user to access another account. Doesn't the backend have a state to be able to tell what the current use ID is based on a session or something?  I would say use that and don't bother with adding it to the query.